# jQuery upload running but not uploading file

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if i could get a bit of advice.

Im trying to upload a file using jquery while keeping the user on the same page.

Whatever i try isnt working. I was wondering if someone could have a look and tell me where im going wrong.

My HTML is

```
<form id="import" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ajax/postimport" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="importSave">Import</button>
</form>
```

This is my jquery

```
$("#importSave").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/postimport',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: {file: $(#filename).val()},
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.result)
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown)
        {

        }
    });
});
```

and then my PHP, which is Laravel 4

```
        if (Input::hasFile('filename')) {
            $file = Input::file('filename');
            $destPath = public_path() . '/uploads/';
            $filename = str_random(10) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destPath, $filename);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upload files by just using the jQuery ajax function. You will need to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object to do this. The problem with Formdata is that it is [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2). If you do want to use it, you can always find plenty tutorials like [this one](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax).

You can also use [a jQuery plugin that does the work for you](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do like this. you are just making post ajax request with only one field file: $(#filename).val().

So you need to use ajax upload library like.
There are several alternatives. But I like most are

http://www.plupload.com/

http://www.uploadify.com/